# Compile only part of template

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I have this piece of code.

```
<h1>Title</h1>

<section class="suggestions-section">
    <h2></h2>
    <div class="special-suggestions">
        {{#each suggestions}}
            <fieldset>
                <legend>{{header}}</legend>
                <img src="{{src}}" alt="">
                <div class="placeholder-buy"></div>
            </fieldset>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</section>
```

Is it possible to compile this code and put h1 in one DOM element and other things in other?

```
const mainContent = $('#main-content');
const header = $('#header');
//compile template
mainContent.prepend(template(data));
header.append(template(data))
```

Can I do this using one template or I have to make two?

Answer (score 1):

Why is your title not part of your template? (I should expect it to be dynamic as well.)

1. You can use 2 different templates in separate files as you say.
2. You can instantiate `template` method twice:

   `var template = Handlebars.template(src);`

   `var templateSecond = Handlebars.template(src2);`
3. Take a look at Partials. kinda like custom filters. But can do the job.

   http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html